# copy and append files in ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have two folders each containing 351 text files and i want to copy the corresponding text from one folder to corresponding file in another folder?
when i am using cat command i am getting an empty file as a result? what could be the problem

my code is :

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR1=$(ls 2/)
DIR2=$(ls 3/)

for each $i in $DIR1; do
for each $j in $DIR2; do
if [[ $i == $j ]];then
sudo cat $i $j >> $j
fi
done
done
```

2/ and 3/ are the folders containing the data...

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DIR1` and `DIR2` contain the file names in directories `2` and `3` respectively. 
Apart from possible problems with spaces or special characters in file names, you would have to use `2/$i` and `3/$j`. `$i` and `$j` alone would reference files with the same names in the current directory (parent of `2` and `3`).

It's better not to parse the output of `ls`.
You don't need two nested loops.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR1=2
DIR2=3

for source in $DIR1/*
do
    dest="$DIR2/$(basename $source)"

    if [ -f "$dest" ]
    then
        sudo cat "$source" >> "$dest"
    fi
done
```

see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Depending on your needs it may be better to run the whole script with `sudo` instead of running `sudo` for every file. The version above will only execute `cat "$source"` as root. When running the whole script as root this includes also `>> "$dest"`.

Comment: when i run the above edits , 2/$i and 3/$j , it changes the file in folder 3 with something like this....... ööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööö

Comment: @Xubair_Lone what exactly did you run? I don't understand "when i run the above edits , 2/$i and 3/$j".

Comment: I just fixed an bug in the `basename` command in my script: must be `$source` instead of `$i`

Comment: yes that did it.. thankyou very much sir....also it gives something like this öööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööööö in the first line...

Comment: it was already there in the 3 folder file and it appended to that directly...thankyou very much for the help... it is working

Comment: @Xubair_Lone: Sorry, I cannot help if I don't know what exactly you did and which files with what content you have.

Comment: Note that running the whole script as root will change the semantics.  At present only the `cat $i $j` is run as root, and not the `>>`.